# jQuery - jeasyui accordion all collapse

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-easyui

I am using the jeasyui accordion.

However by default it always shows the first accordion in open state. I want to see if I can show all the accordions in collapsed state when the page loads.

This is the link I have referred for the documentation. http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/accordion.php

My code:

```
<div id="someid" class="easyui-accordion" data-options="multiple:true" >

        <div title="About Accordion" 
            style="overflow: auto; padding: 10px;" >
            <h3 style="color: #0099FF;">Accordion for jQuery</h3>
            <p>Accordion is a part of easyui framework for jQuery. It lets
                you define your accordion component on web page more easily.</p>
        </div>

        <div title="About easyui" data-options="selected:true" style="padding: 10px;">easyui help you build your web page easily</div>

        <div title="Tree Menu">another set of information</div>

    </div>
```

FINAL SOLUTION:

I added the following code in the javascript function to collapse the panels.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var panels = $('.easyui-accordion').accordion('panels');
    $.each(panels, function(){
        this.panel('collapse');
    });
    });
```

Comment: @BishopBarber that solution is for jQuery Accordion. I am using a different library.

Comment: I apologize, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is, at load, get all the accordion panels and call the `collapse` method on each of them to collapse them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var panels = $('#aa').accordion('panels');
    $.each(panels, function() {
        this.panel('collapse');
    });
});
```

Comment: @E2241 You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer so future readers can easily find the solution.

Comment: I was trying to accept the answer however 1) the jsfiddle code doesnt work because it does not give you a chance to import jquery easy ui library js framework. Its got all others there. 2) the code you have sent is mostly from another link I have seen on this website. 3) The code is still incomplete and needs to have document.ready function. Hence i put the solution in my question itself.

Comment: @E2241 I really don't mind you not accepting the answer, since now it's on the top of the page and future readers will find it first. However I do not agree with you. 1) As far as I'm concerned, the jsfiddle does work. No, you can not easily import jquery easy ui library js framework, because there is no cdn version available. The best I could do was host it on orionhub. 2) The code I proposed was indeed inspired by [this answer](http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=5035.msg12530#msg12530). However, future users will find it more easily on StackOverflow.

Comment: @E2241 3) Omitting document.ready in the answer does not make it incomplete. It is implied. Besides, in my jsfiddle, you have it. 4) The answer you put in the question is the same exact thing I have in my jsfiddle, so I don't understand your logic. Anyways, I'm glad you resolved your problem, have a good day!

Comment: I was not trying to offend you. The only reason I didnt accept the answer was it was not going to solve the issue. However I will accept the fact that you did point me in the right direction. I am sorry but the JsFiddle will not work without the easy ui library js. Hence that link which you have posted is basically of no use and that made me hesitant in selecting an answer which basically does not work.

Comment: @E2241 I'm sorry, you're absolutely right. Only I have access to the hosted files. I tried running the fiddle in incognito mode and it does not work indeed. Once again, I'm sorry for my stubbornness, I'm going to change my answer and remove the fiddle, since I am not able to host the files.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the documentation you've provided you need to set the selected property to false much link the example

```
<div title="Title2" data-options="iconCls:'icon-reload',selected:true" style="padding:10px;">

data-options="selected:false" // this is what you need in your first div
```

put the above in your first div. I'm driving blind as you haven't provided your code

Cheers

Truez

Comment: I havbe tried using that. It doesnt collapse the first div. However when i set it to true for other divs it shows up as open accordion.

Answer (score 0):

In it's documentation [here](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/accordion.php),in **Container Options**, you can use option `selected`,I tried to set it's value as **-1** and it worked,like this:

```
<div id="aa" class="easyui-accordion" style="width:300px;height:200px;" data-options="
                selected:-1" >
    <div title="Title1"  style="overflow:auto;padding:10px;">
        <h3 style="color:#0099FF;">Accordion for jQuery</h3>
        <p>Accordion is a part of easyui framework for jQuery. 
        It lets you define your accordion component on web page more easily.</p>
    </div>
    <div title="Title2" data-options="iconCls:'icon-reload'" style="padding:10px;">
        content2
    </div>
    <div title="Title3">
        content3
    </div>
</div>
```

[Jsbin Example](http://jsbin.com/bemizulixi/1/edit?html,output)